# How to calculate over head of XML

Tags: xml

I have an XML file and I would like to calculate the overhead of this XML file, how would I go about doing this? As of note it is of the following schema http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1636/1636.1-2007/TestResults.xsd.

Comment: Could you specify what kind of overhead you are looking for? Extra time spent processing the file? Extra size of the file? And it would also be interesting to know what you want to compare it to.

Comment: please define overhead in this context.

Comment: Extra size of the file. And I don't want to compare it to anything just figure out the overhead for documentation. @mtak

Comment: And how are we supposed to go about doing that? If you can't tell us how much space your current data takes, it would be impossible to tell you how much overhead it has (`bytesWithXML-bytesWithoutXML=overheadInBytes`)

Comment: @mtak well that is why i am asking the question since I am not sure where to start

Comment: it takes up 1kb of space with including all the xml info

Comment: sounds like an asinine thing to do, but count the characters that make up tags and delimiters, and count up the number of chars in element and attribute values, and compare them I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate the overhead XML introduces into a file, you would first have to get the original file size. For example for a list of products:

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
```

This would add up to 24 bytes. If you put this data in an XML schema, it would look like this:

```
<ProductList>
  <Product>
    <Name>item1</Name>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Name>item2</Name>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Name>item3</Name>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Name>item4</Name>
  </Product>
</ProductList>
```

This list takes up 221 bytes. The overhead created is 221-24=**197 bytes**, or 197/24*100=**820.8%**.

Comment: don't forget attribute values!

Comment: This answer describes how to do the calculation.  You can easily get the XML file size.  A simple way to get the size of the non-XML content, without manually differentiating what's what and counting characters is to view the file output, copy and paste it into a text editor, and save it.